# Angular directive - select dropdown array or object model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What i want to accomplish is make a directive that is able to generate a select dropdown with either array or object model. I get from my server an array of objects and what i want to is generate my template that only uses the "user_id" to display my options. Here's what i tried:

HTML

```
<ng-select options="error.currentOrder.loggedPackages" selected="error.selected.user" object-field="user_id"></ng-select>
```

The template

```
<div class="select dropdown">
    <button data-toggle="dropdown"><% selected %><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>

    <ul ng-if="!objectField" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="option in options" ng-click="selectOption($index)"><% option %></li>
    </ul>

    <ul ng-if="objectField" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="option in options" ng-click="selectOption($index)"><% option[objectField] %></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
Application.directive('ngSelect', function () {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        replace : true,
        templateUrl : '/templates/directives/select.html',
        scope : {
            options: '=',
            selected: '=',
            objectField: '='
        },
        controller : ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.selectOption = function (index) {
                $scope.selected = $scope.options[index];
            }
        }],

        link: function(scope, elem, attrs)
        {
            console.log(scope.objectField);
            console.log('seleeeect');
        }
    }
});

Application.controller('ErrorReportingController', ['$scope', '$http', 'initData', 'ServerActions', function($scope, $http, initData, ServerActions) {

    var error = this;
    error.initData = initData;

    error.selected = {

    }

    error.submitOrder = function (orderID) {
        ServerActions.fetchData('/packing/error.action', {id : orderID}).then(
            function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                error.currentOrder = response.data;
            }
        )
    };

    console.log(error.initData);

}]);
```

Comment: Just a note id avoid naming your custom directives in angular's core `ng` namespace. Other devs may mistake it for a core directive. Also angular has a core directive `ng-options` which you apply to a `select` element. it can be used with arrays or objects. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: i know about that directive but it's not so useful to me since the selects can't be styled properly. thanks for the other tip tough

Comment: easier to help if you have a plunker, but from what I understood you just want a custom dropdown... not a select... coz you want to customize the item ul right?

Comment: yes. i'm looking for a way to control the listed items via attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understood correctly, you need directive with dynamic template, which depends on the type of `options` and presence of `object-field` attribute. Also, if `object-field` is nested it is going to be tricky :)

Here is how I would solve it:

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link data-require="font-awesome@*" data-semver="4.3.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.6" data-semver="1.4.6" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <h3>Array of Strings: {{selectedString}}</h3>
    <app-select 
      options="stringModel"
      selected="selectedString"
    ></app-select>

    <h3>Array of Objects: {{selectedObject}}</h3>
    <app-select 
      options="objectModel"
      selected="selectedObject" 
      object-field="some.nested.field"
    ></app-select>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app',[]).
  controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.stringModel = ["First", "Second", "Third"];
    $scope.objectModel = [{some: {nested: {field: "First"}}}, {some: {nested: {field: "Second"}}}, {some: {nested: {field: "Third"}}}];
    $scope.selectedString = $scope.stringModel[1];
    $scope.selectedObject = $scope.objectModel[2];
  }]).
  directive('appSelect', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
      scope: {
        'options': '=',
        'selected': '='
      },
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true,
      controller: [function() {
        this.visible = false;
        this.selectItem = function($index) {
          this.selected = this.options[$index];
          this.visible = false;
        };
      }],
      compile: function(template, attrs) {
        var isObject = !!attrs['objectField'],
            html =  '<div class="select dropdown">' +
                      '<button data-toggle="dropdown">' + 
                        '{{vm.' + (isObject ? 'selected.' + attrs.objectField : 'selected') + '}}' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-angle-down" ng-click="vm.visible=!vm.visible"></i>' + 
                      '</button>' +
                      '<ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-if="vm.visible">' +
                        '<li ng-repeat="option in vm.options track by $index" ng-click="vm.selectItem($index)">' +
                          '{{' + (isObject ? 'option.' + attrs.objectField : 'option') + '}}' +
                        '</li>' +
                      '</ul>' +
                    '</div>';              
        return function postLink(scope, el) {
          el.html(html);
          $compile(el.contents())(scope);
        };
      }
    }
  }]);
```

And if you need to load template via URL, it is also possible. Since compile function is called after template is loaded, you can substitute some placeholders like '{{selected}}' and '{{option}}' with something else in compile function:

```
...
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      compile: function(template, attrs) {
        var isObject = !!attrs['objectField'],
            selected = isObject ? 'selected.' + attrs.objectField : 'selected',
            option = isObject ? 'option.' + attrs.objectField : 'option';
            html =  template.html().
              replace('{{selected}}', '{{vm.' + selected + '}}').
              replace('{{option}}', '{{' + option + '}}');
        return function postLink(scope, el) {
          el.html(html);
          $compile(el.contents())(scope);
        };
      }
...
```

**template.html**

```
<div class="select dropdown">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown">
    {{selected}}<i class="fa fa-angle-down" ng-click="vm.visible=!vm.visible"></i>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-if="vm.visible">
    <li ng-repeat="option in vm.options track by $index" ng-click="vm.selectItem($index)">{{option}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Plunker**

- static template: http://plnkr.co/edit/DSOCHqKDFauxCVOEMNA9?p=preview
- template loaded via URL: http://plnkr.co/edit/zLkpUxQCGNkZIyFb0vC5?p=preview

*More about dynamic templates you can reed here:*

http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/

Comment: i see what you did there. so if i use dynamic templates i need to write the html as string and work my variables into it, or can i use templateUrl in some way?

Comment: yes, you can load the template, substitute parameters in compile function and do the same.

Comment: well, i still have to learn about compile function and dynamic templates, because i don't understand very well what happens but your post has been helpful, so thank you. does the compile function give me access to template url and i change it in or something like that?

Comment: @JonathanSzekely I've updated the post to show how to use directive with template loaded via URL.